# Port forwarding

Tags: network, monterey, firewall, pfctl

I would like to intercept the tcp traffic from a device on my network. I cannot change the destination but I set the router IP to the IP of my M1 Mac Mini.

I used to do this with ipfw on a virtual machine running Ubuntu. I used these command to accomplish the interception:

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 176.58.117.69 --dport 10004 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.245.32
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -t nat -p tcp -d 176.58.117.69 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.245.32
```

I want to obtain the same result with pf on MacOS Monterey. I added a new anchor file under /private/etc/pf.anchors containing:
`rdr pass proto tcp from any to 176.58.117.69 -> self`

Sending a packet to that address on port 10004 from another computer with the IP of the Mac Mini as router IP and running `nc -l 10004` on the Mac Mini does not return anything.

I checked that the rules do not contain an error with
`sudo pfctl -vnf /private/etc/pf.conf`
The rules were loaded with `pfctl -ef /private/etc/pf.conf`
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of - frustrating - failed attempts I got this working.
In short:
Create a file with this rule:

```
rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -> sss.sss.sss.sss
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the destination IP I wish to intercept. sss.sss.sss.sss is the secondary IP of the Mac Mini. There might be simpler or better ways but this works.
Put this file in /private/etc/pf.anchors. Make it have the same privileges as com.apple in that directory.
You should verify that the rule contains no errors with:

```
sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/<your file name>
```

Then edit /private/etc/pf.conf. Add:

```
rdr-anchor "your file name"
```

*under the existing rdr-anchor*. This was the detail that I was missing. At the end of pf.conf add:

```
anchor "your file name"
load anchor "your file name" from "full path of your file"
```

I enabled port forwarding with:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

I'm not sure this is really needed.
The I loaded my rules with:

```
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
```

You may need to explicitly enable pf to get it running.
And then, as if by magic, it works. 
Now all I need is to install the process that does something with the intercepted data.

Comment: Are there extra steps to be taken to "explicitly enable pf to get it running"? And if yes, can you add the explanation to the answer?