# Port forwarding on macOS Sonoma 14.1.1 (23B81)

Tags: macos, network, pfctl

I would like to setup port forwarding on my MacBook, but I don`t get it working, even after studying a lot of questions here and other blog posts.

I have some SSH tunels opened from another machine to my MacBook to be able to access other services via these tunnels. The tunnels are working fine. I checked this with `nc -z 127.0.0.1 <port>` and even with cURL.

To be able the use these tunnels transparently, I assigned each system a custom IP address via `/etc/hosts`.

```
gitlab.acme.com    100.0.100.100
```

To forward all trafic from 100.0.100.100:443 to 127.0.0.1:30030 I wrote the following rule:

```
rdr pass proto tcp from any to 10.0.100.100 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 30030
```

But I am unable to apply this rule. My last attempt was to put this rule in `/etc/pf.conf`:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"

rdr pass proto tcp from any to 10.0.100.100 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 30030

dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Are these virtualized ghosts or is your Mac acting as a firewall/router to a summer of physical hosts behind it?

Comment: After looking at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441969/port-forwarding, just wondering if you enabled port forwarding with `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` and reloaded the pf rules with `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf`?

Comment: @allan, no, I use it as normal working machine

Comment: @luckman212, yes, I set net.inet.ip.forwarding=1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but if tinkering with `pf.conf` isn't working for you, it might be worth trying this open-source app: https://github.com/hronro/iPortForwarder